# Split an array into 4 portions

Tags: java, split

I have to create a method that divides the array of integers taken as input into an array that is made in this way:

- The first portion is composed of the elements which, divided by 4, generate rest 0
- The second portion is composed of the elements which, divided by 4, give rest 1
- The third portion is composed of the elements which, divided by 4, give remainder 2
- The fourth portion is composed of the elements, divided by 4, give rest 3

For example, the following array:

**[0,2,4,5,6,8,7,9,10,12,14,15,17,20,1]**

must become this here:

**[0,4,8,12,20,5,9,17,1,2,6,10,14,7,15]**

The result I get is:

**[0,4,5,8,6,2,7,9,10,12,14,15,17,20,1]**

Within subsequences no matter the order of items, just be in the subsequence correct.

I wrote this method but doen't work properly, some items are out of place.

```
public static void separate4Colors(int[] a) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int h = a.length - 1;
    while(k <= h) {
        if(a[k] % 4 == 0) {
            swap(a, k, i);
            k++;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if(a[k] % 4 == 1) {
            swap(a, k, i);
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else if(a[k] % 4 == 2) {
            k++;
        }
        else {
            while(h > k && a[k] % 4 == 3)
                h--;
            swap(a, k, h);
            h--;
        }
    }
}

private static void swap(int[] a, int x, int y) {
    int temp = a[x];
    a[x] = a[y];
    a[y] = temp;
}
```

Can someone help me fix it?

---

A similar exercise that I've done and that work is to divide the array into 3 portions instead that 4:

```
public static void separate3Colors(int[] a) {
    int j = 0;
    int k = a.length - 1;
    int i = 0;
    while(j <= k) {
        if(a[j] % 3 == 0) { 
            swap(a, j, i); 
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        else if(a[j] % 3 == 1) {
            j++;
        }
        else { 
            swap(a, j, k);
            k--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and  please  provide an exemple of data where you algorithm doesn' work. What's the input data, what you expect, and what you get, actually., Smallest as possible, thanls.

Comment: @MichelBillaud I think he did provide the input data and expected result though, just missing the actual result and the `swap()` function.

Comment: @gosu of course, but I also try to make him look for a very small example so he will be able run it with paper and pencil, and see when things go wrong wrt. his mental model.

Comment: @MichelBillaud Thanks for the answers, I updated the question of adding details.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single line by sorting the array using a comparator that compares numbers modulo 4. Unfortunately, it requires an array of `Integer` objects.

Another approach would be writing the results into a different array. You can walk the array once to determine indexes at which the values with each remainder will start, and then walk the array again to make an ordered copy:

```
int[] index = new int[4];
for(int n : a) {
    int r = n % 4;
    if (r != 3) {
        index[r+1]++;
    }
}
index[2] += index[1];
index[3] += index[2];
// At this point each index[k] has the position where elements
// with remainder of k will start
int[] res = new int[a.length];
for(int n : a) {
    res[index[n%4]++] = n;
}
```

This places the re-ordered array into the `res` variable.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/DX0HXn)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I have to do the procedure only making swap and index updates.

Comment: @user3808470 Then you could implement your favorite stable sort method, but instead of using `if (a < b)` for comparison use `if ((a%4) < (b%4))`. Bubble sort is stable, and is easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

This exercice is obviously a variant of the famous *Dutch National Flag Problem* by the late E. Dijkstra  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem
and the same resolution technique can be applied (with success, of course).

Consider that, at some point while running your algorithm, the arrays has five parts. One part contains numbers you know have with remainder 0, one part for remainders 1, etc. And one part for unclassified numbers. Each step of the algorithm consists of

- looking at the first unclassified number
- swapping some numbers at the borders so the number falls in the right part.

So the "unsorted" zone shrinks by one unit.

Sometimes a picture helps (go figure). I chose the have the unclassified elements between the 1's and the 2's.

```
 000000000111111uuuuuuu22222333333333
                ?
```

If remainder of the number under test is 1, just leave it there. If it is zero, swap it with the first "1". etc.

At the beginning, of course, the situation is depicted as

```
 uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
 ?
```

Comment: If there is a message to remember about this exercice, it is "***draw pictures! it helps a lot:!**"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The I did the draw but I still have some problems with the indices.. especially when the item has rest 2 or 3, the other two cases I made them..

Comment: Use the picrtre to decide what you do with the indices. For example, at the beginning of a new zone  a=first 1, b=first u, c=first 2, d=first 3 (cant do a picture in a comment). So at the beginning of the algorithme; a=b=0  and c=d=n.
For the case of 2, exchange first "u" (position b - growing the "2" part) and last (position c-1). For 3, permute the last 2, the last and first u's